# dict does not reference elements? Python2.7 changed behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, reference, garbage-collection, python-2.x

Given the example:

```
>>> import gc
>>> d = { 1 : object() }
>>> gc.get_referrers(d[1])
[] # Python 2.7
[{1: <object object at 0x003A0468>}] # Python 2.5
```

**Why** is `d` not listed as refererrer to  to the object?

**EDIT1:** Although the dict in d references the object, why is the dictionairy not listed?

Comment: Also works in Python 2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) mentions that:

> This function will only locate those containers which support garbage
>   collection; extension types which do refer to other objects but do not
>   support garbage collection will not be found.

Seems that dictionaries do not support it.

And here is why:

> The garbage collector tries to avoid tracking simple containers which
>   can’t be part of a cycle. In Python 2.7, this is now true for tuples
>   and dicts containing atomic types (such as ints, strings, etc.).
>   Transitively, a dict containing tuples of atomic types won’t be
>   tracked either. This helps reduce the cost of each garbage collection
>   by decreasing the number of objects to be considered and traversed by
>   the collector.
>
> — From [What's new in Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html)

It seems that `object()` is considered an *atomic type*, and trying this with an instance of a user-defined class (that is, not `object`) confirms this as your code now works.

```
# Python 2.7
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> r = A()
>>> d = {1: r}
>>> del r
>>> gc.get_referrers(d[1])
[{1: <__main__.A instance at 0x0000000002663708>}]
```

*See also [issue 4688](http://bugs.python.org/issue4688)*.

Comment: I mean the real object behind `d`, not the variable name.

Comment: @jamylak there was a bug initially, I forgot the quotes around `d`, but fixed it quickly.

Comment: @User that is how `get_referrers` works. It will return you a list of `dict`s implementing namespaces.

Comment: The interesting part is that we can `del r` and then `gc.get_referrers()` returns an empty list. Yet `d` still refers to that instance. It looks like dictionaries do not support garbage collection atm. You can `del r` and store do `lis = d[1].values()` and then `lis in gc.get_referrers(lis[0])` is True.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hmm, you' re right. I guess I'll have to completely rewrite my answer then…

Comment: So my Question is: Why did dicts loose garbage collection support.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's not the original bugreport as it's filed already against Python 2.7. And it mentions that things might be broken due to the optimization being discussed here and implemented in ticket 4688.

Comment: @kirelagin: Getting there; had too little sleep last night. :-P

Answer (score 1):

This is a change in how objects are tracked in Python 2.7; tuples and dictionaries containing only atomic types (including instances of `object()`), which would never require cycle breaking, are not listed anymore.

See http://bugs.python.org/issue4688; this was implemented to avoid a performance issues with creating loads of tuples or dictionaries.

The work-around is to add an object to your dictionary that *does* need tracking:

```
>>> gc.is_tracked(d)
False
>>> class Foo(object): pass
...
>>> d['_'] = Foo()
>>> gc.is_tracked(d)
True
>>> d in gc.get_referrers(r)
True
```

Once tracked, a dictionary only goes back to being untracked after a gc collection cycle:

```
>>> del d['_']
>>> gc.is_tracked(d)
True
>>> d in gc.get_referrers(r)
True
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> gc.is_tracked(d)
False
>>> d in gc.get_referrers(r)
False
```

Comment: It's a list, first of all, not a dictionary.

Comment: I want the dictionairies to show up and the objects never showed up in Python2.5 . hmm.

Comment: `class X(object):pass ; x = X(); x.a = object(); print gc.get_referrers(x.a)` => `[]`